# Error updating maven configuration : String index out of range : 105

Tags: java, eclipse, maven

I have a problem with my eclipse configuration. Since this morning, when I right-click / Maven / Update project Configuration it says "Updating Maven project has encountered a problem. Could not update project  configuration."

Details says : String index out of range : 105.

I've checked Build path / Deployment assembly / . project / restart Eclipse ... it seems OK. Maven install works fine.

Any Idea ? Thanks.

Comment: Use android studio...

Comment: It's a Struts2 project. Everyone use eclipse in my company. I can't change.

Comment: Hello, It work's again . And i don't know why. Eclipse is magic ..